# How to join 3 tables without duplicate columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, azure-sql-database

Query :

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.employer_job
LEFT JOIN dbo.employer_user
  ON dbo.employer_job.employer_id = dbo.employer_user.employer_user_id
LEFT JOIN dbo.company_profile
  ON dbo.company_profile.company_id = dbo.employer_user.company_id
```

Duplicate column results :

[image]

`dbo.employer_job` schema :

[image]

`dbo.employer_user` schema :

[image]

`dbo.comnpany_profile` schema :

[image]

How do I remove the duplicate `company_id` column? My Python app won't accept duplicated columns from the database. Most suggest to use left join but that's not solving the issue.

Comment: List the columns you want explicitly.  Voila!  No duplicates.

Comment: @GordonLinoff my python app is throwing an error when I try to do this "pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Ambiguous column name 'company_id'. (209) (SQLExecDirectW)")"

Comment: There are no duplicate columns. One is `employer_user.company_id` while the other is `company_profile.company_id`. Those aren't the same columns, as they're coming from different tables. If you don't want both in your `SELECT`, then don't use `SELECT *`. You're telling SQL Server you want **all** the columns and it is giving them to you. FYI, [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/); you should be aliasing your objects and qualifying your columns with the object's alias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use *, but list the columns you want from each table (preferably with an alias).

```
SELECT EJ.job_id, EJ.employer_id, .... 
FROM dbo.employer_job EJ 
...
```

It's verbose, but how else would the database engine know what you'd like to see?

Answer (score 2):

You need to list the columns explicitly -- **and qualify them**:

```
SELECT ej.*, eu.employee_user_email,
       cp.company_name, . . . 
FROM dbo.employer_job ej LEFT JOIN
     dbo.employer_user eu
     ON ej.employer_id = eu.employer_user_id LEFT JOIN
     dbo.company_profile cp
     ON cp.company_id = eu.company_id;
```

I'm not sure if the `LEFT JOIN` is really needed.  Note that this introduces table aliases, so the query is easier to write and to read.